# what will happen to the message if it is in the message queue while kafka instances got bounce?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is this a possible case for data loss? If due to unerlying hardware issue, kafka is having request queue queued up, If this time, we shutdown/bounce that kafka broker, What will happen to the follower?
what will happen to the message is the queue?

```
kafka.network:type=RequestChannel,name=RequestQueueSize
Size of the request queue. A congested request queue will not be able to process incoming or outgoing requests
```

Based on what I learn from kafka, this should be in networklayer, does that mean the message in the queue will be dropped, is this a case of data loss?

Answer (score 1):

The message still present in the request queue has not yet been appended to log nor replicated to replicas.
Depending on your producer (mainly `acks` attribute) and broker configuration (`min.insync.replicas`), you're risking data loss.
Set `acks` to a higher value to ensure that your request has been processed.

Comment: Thanks Adam, That means, if the broker is gone. The message in the queue of the broker should drop the data itself right? we have rf3, meaning same request still possible make it to other replica. a potential data loss but not really matters if proper settting in others.